# Unity2D Collision issues, gameObject.tag if statement not working with own gameObject and tag

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I apologize in advance if this question has a really easy solution, but I am working on a school project and can't find anything to help me with this issue. The (gameObject.tag=="Large Asteroid") always returns with a false, which doesn't make sense to me, because I belelive I am doing that piece of code right. This code I found online, and it's from an earlier version of unity, so that might be the issue. I just need some help with the if statement.

` void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D c)
{

```
    print("hitting");

    if (c.gameObject.tag.Equals("Bullet"))
    {

        //// Destroy the bullet
        Destroy(c.gameObject);

        print("girlworld");

        // If large asteroid spawn new ones
        if (gameObject.tag == "Large Asteroid")
        {

            print("startgirl");
            // Spawn small asteroids
            Instantiate(medAsteroid,
                new Vector3(transform.position.x - .5f,
                    transform.position.y - .5f, 0),
                    Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 90));

            // Spawn small asteroids
            Instantiate(medAsteroid,
                new Vector3(transform.position.x + .5f,
                    transform.position.y + .0f, 0),
                    Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 0));

            // Spawn small asteroids
            Instantiate(medAsteroid,
                new Vector3(transform.position.x + .5f,
                    transform.position.y - .5f, 0),
                    Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 270));


        }
        if (tag.Equals("Medium Asteroid"))
        {
            // Spawn small asteroids
            Instantiate(smallAsteroid,
                new Vector3(transform.position.x - .5f,
                    transform.position.y - .5f, 0),
                    Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 90));

            // Spawn small asteroids
            Instantiate(smallAsteroid,
                new Vector3(transform.position.x + .5f,
                    transform.position.y + .0f, 0),
                    Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 0));

            // Spawn small asteroids
            Instantiate(smallAsteroid,
                new Vector3(transform.position.x + .5f,
                    transform.position.y - .5f, 0),
                    Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 270));


        }
        else
        {

            // Just a small asteroid destroyed
        }





        // Destroy the current asteroid
        Destroy(gameObject);

    }
}`
```

Comment: Have you tried using OnTriggerEnter2D instead of Collision? It works a lot better and faster.

Comment: @Mintvbz why should this be true exactly? They are called for completely different conditions also ...

Comment: OnTriggerEnter, being called when two GameObjects collide is called specifically for triggers and Rigidbody's, which already run pretty fast depending on the settings. The OnCollisionEnter can be slower sometimes because it does not need the fast-running physics or Colliders. Also, colliders with OnTriggerEnter can be more efficient if you want to change the hit-boxes or change how it is set up and/or located.

Comment: In general please use the correct tags! Note that [`unityscript`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a JavaScript flavor like custom language used in early Unity versions and is long **deprecated** by now!

Answer (score 0):

First use compareTag `if(c.CompareTag("Bullet"))`
check : https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.CompareTag.html

The (gameObject.tag=="Large Asteroid") always returns with a false :
-The script you attached to this object must have this tag "Large Asteroid"-
As far as I understand from the code, the problem is that the object that this code calls does not have this tag.

"gameObject" means the object that attached your code in to.
Maybe It'll help you more : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0XgOJ7ioSuA

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure your gameObject have the tag "Large Asteroid" on the top of the inspector tab.

Try using `if(this.gameObject.tag == "Large Asteroid")`